# JSON - Convert Object to JSON Array

Tags: java, json, serialization

i try to convert a class object which are generated via Reflection and convert them to JSON string. following is my methods

```
public Object creatObjectAsString(String className) {
    Object objects = null;
    try {
        objects = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance( Class.forName(className), 1);
        //System.out.println(objects.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objects ;
}
public String convertPlainObjectToJSON( Object obj,boolean isArray){
    String jsonString="",tempJSON="";
    JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
    tempJSON = serializer.serialize(obj);
    if(isArray){
        jsonString="["+tempJSON+"]";
    }else{
        jsonString=tempJSON;
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

I have hard coded the following lines since i did not know how to create JSON Array which is not the correct way of programming.

```
if(isArray){
    jsonString="["+tempJSON+"]";
}else{
    jsonString=tempJSON;
}
```

when i printed the `convertPlainObjectToJSON` result of  method i get the following `[[null]]` which is not expected.

what is the mistake i make.

Please correct me.

Comment: why not try using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Comment: I have also seen that but my case is different where i create object using Reflection and convert the object to JSON or JSON Array.

Comment: if you notice your output, u can see `[[` double square braces, which means the `JSONSerializer` has already converted it to an `JSONArray`. You needn't do it manually. And regd the `null`, make sure that your `obj` passed to the method `convertPlainObjectToJSON` is not null.

Comment: yes, the object i pass is null, because i just want to pass the empty json string/Array

Comment: An empty array is something different from `null`. You can e.g. create one using `new Object[0]`. @R.J, your comment seems like it would make a good answer, do you want to post it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice your output, you can see `[[` (**double square braces**), which means the `JSONSerializer` has already converted it to an `JSONArray`. Therefore, you needn't do it again manually.

And regarding the `null` between them, it is because you're passing `null` to the `convertPlainObjectToJSON`. Send a newly created object array (**as @MvG** mentioned), `new Object[0]`, and you'll get what you want!

Always remember that `blank` and `null` are not the same!